# Single list with data from sub (nested) - node Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to create a list with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter or other, with all name of all month? The problem is that name are in a sub-node as image.

[image]

I try with this code, but I get an empty list. If you can do this, how can I do?

```
mAdapter2 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DailyItem, TestHolder>(DailyItem.class, R.layout.test_layout_item, TestHolder.class, mDatabase.child("Year").child("2018")) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final TestHolder viewHolder, final DailyItem model, final int position) {
        final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);
        final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
        viewHolder.bindToPost(model);
    }
};
mRecycler2.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
```

I looked at other questions but I did not find a similar situation. Thank you

Comment: What is displaying now?

Comment: Nothing...the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` (and the other adapters in FirebaseUI) show the direct child nodes of a location or query. While they can show lower level properties for each child node, they don't support showing nested child nodes as top-level list items.

In general I recommend modeling the JSON in your database to reflect what you're showing on the screen. So if you want to show a list of months on screen, consider storing a **list** of months in the database.

This list could replace the current nested tree. But it could also be additional data. Duplicating data is very common in NoSQL databases. For some more on this topic, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Ok thanks, then in this way is not possible. I try see nosql data modeling. But If I create an array list, and populate it with firebase method there is the same problem?